# Complete instructions wanted how to install zeromq-4.1.2

Tags: 14.04, install-from-source

I've cleaned all with `make clean` in both libsodium and zeromq folders, then reinstalleid libsodium-0.6.0 and zeromq-4.1.2.

libsodium seems installed OK, but installation of zeromq failed on `make check` with numerous errors complaining of not finding of **libsodium.so.10** look like:

```
/home/user/sources/zeromq-4.1.2/.libs/lt-test_sub_forward: error while loading shared libraries: libsodium.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
FAIL: test_sub_forward
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact steps you used to install libsodium-0.6.0

Comment: ok, I described, nothing special

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the libsodium-0.6.0 `make install` does not run `ldconfig` to update the linker cache. Run `sudo ldconfig` (or `sudo ldconfig -v`) and then try again.

Comment: OMG! I've read about that in installation guide, but completely forgot of it. Thank you!